# Issue with a tag in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a route

```
Route::get('/Appraisal_cycle', [
            'uses' => $namespacePrefix . 'Users@Appraisal2', 
            'as' => 'Appraisal_cycle'
        ]);
```

and href

```
<a href="{{ route('voyager.users.Appraisal_cycle') }}" class="btn btn-primary">
    Appraisal Form
</a>
```

And my function

```
public function Appraisal2() {
    echo 'hii';
}
```

but when i click this a tag it will shows page not error.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in `route`  `Users` is a controller or any other class?

Comment: @LuckySaini its controller

Comment: `Appraisal2()` should return an *HttpResponse* or *view*

Comment: actually what you excepting the result ? in your code if the route is ok then its supposed to show you the 'hii' text. can you explain what error you getting

Comment: what roue you are going on link

Answer (score 0):

Here is your route

```
Route::get('/Appraisal_cycle', [
            'uses' => $namespacePrefix . 'Users@Appraisal2', 
            'as' => 'Appraisal_cycle'
        ]);
```

and you can try to write this code in your controller

**For APIs**

```
public function Appraisal2()
{
    return \Response::json([
        'hello' => "World"
    ]);
}
```

**For Web**

```
public function Appraisal2()
{
    return view("home");
}
```

And your `home.blade.php` file should be inside `resources -> views` directory